# How to use angular-2-dropdown-multiselect

Tags: angular, multi-select

I am using [angular-2-dropdown-multiselect](https://github.com/softsimon/angular-2-dropdown-multiselect)

I have installed this lib using

```
npm install angular-2-dropdown-multiselect
```

then added the entry in `system.config.js` under `map`

```
'angular-2-dropdown-multiselect': 'node_modules/angular-2-dropdown-multiselect',
```

and under `packages`

```
'angular-2-dropdown-multiselect': {
        main: 'index.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
  }
```

but still this is showing

```
GET http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular-2-dropdown-multiselect/index.js 404 (Not Found)
scheduleTask @ zone.js:1645
ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:255
Zone.scheduleMacroTask @ zone.js:168
(anonymous) @ zone.js:1669
send @ VM519:3
fetchTextFromURL @ system.src.js:1051
(anonymous) @ system.src.js:1778
ZoneAwarePromise @ zone.js:536
(anonymous) @ system.src.js:1777
(anonymous) @ system.src.js:2806
(anonymous) @ system.src.js:3384
(anonymous) @ system.src.js:3707
(anonymous) @ system.src.js:4099
(anonymous) @ system.src.js:4562
(anonymous) @ system.src.js:4831
(anonymous) @ system.src.js:407
ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:242
Zone.run @ zone.js:113
(anonymous) @ zone.js:520
ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:275
Zone.runTask @ zone.js:151
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:418
ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:349
2017-03-09 15:15:11.555 (index):23 Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular-2-dropdown-multiselect/index.js
    Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular-2-dropdown-multiselect/index.js
        at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn [as _onreadystatechange] (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:889:29) [<root>]
        at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:151:47) [<root> => <root>]
        at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:345:33) [<root>]
    Error loading http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular-2-dropdown-multiselect/index.js as "angular-2-dropdown-multiselect" from http://localhost:3000/app/app.module.js
        at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn [as _onreadystatechange] (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:889:29) [<root>]
        at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:151:47) [<root> => <root>]
        at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:345:33) [<root>]
    Error loading http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular-2-dropdown-multiselect/index.js as "angular-2-dropdown-multiselect" from http://localhost:3000/app/app.module.js
(anonymous) @ (index):23
ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:242
Zone.run @ zone.js:113
(anonymous) @ zone.js:520
ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:275
Zone.runTask @ zone.js:151
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:418
ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:349
2017-03-09 15:15:12.647 zone.js:1645 GET http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular-2-dropdown-multiselect/index.js 404 (Not Found)
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: should you use angular-2-dropdown-multiselect/src/multiselect-dropdown.js directly for there is no index.js in the package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
'angular-2-dropdown-multiselect': 'node_modules/angular-2-dropdown-multiselect/src/multiselect-dropdown.js',
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/1HDj2zDnmL9LttmVPwZ2?p=preview)**

Comment: `Dependencies Bootstrap CSS 3 or 4, Font Awesome (optional)` https://github.com/softsimon/angular-2-dropdown-multiselect

Comment: how can I set width? I am trying style property with width:100%. but not working :(